# What is the kind of ID that short url use?

Tags: url-shortener

What is the kind that they use in their short urls?

The kind where instead of being just numbers, they increment in things like:
7Hna7z

and that. I'm just starting to get into programming and I was thinking on doing that for a project.
I just need a name or something to google it, or if anybody has a PHP or MySQL tutorial onto how to do it I would appreciate it greatly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an alphanumeric key that has been generated. It's guaranteed to be unique. In PHP, this can be a uniqID. You can see the documentation for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: For url-shorteners that key is an indexed field in a database where the real, long url exists.

Comment: PHP's uniqid() function generates a rather long hexdecimal number.  Most shorteners use the full alphabet, including uppercase letter to generate a much shorter representation of a typical integer.